# Meaning of ir as a prefix in Odoo

Tags: odoo

Reading odoo API or source code your would encounter the term ir ( usually as a prefix ), I can't seem to figure out what does it stand for ?

for example

```
ir_sequence
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is *Information Repository*.

Comment: Great! How do you know that? It doesn't seem to be anywhere in the code.

Comment: @AdanCortes I googled for it and from `res` time ago, but I think I did not find it in code comments.

Comment: @AdanCortes see https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/Miscellaneous/info_repository/

Answer (score 1):

Although there's no official statement on the matter AFAIK, I tend to think about it as *Internal Resource* (various resources the system needs to work fine, but not actually meaningful for normal users day-to-day work), just as I think about the `res` prefix as *Resource* (which is not internal, it's for normal usage).

As example, `res.config` is to create visual configuration wizards to be presented to a user that may not be the sysadmin (he could be just the sales responsible for example), but many settings are actually stored as `ir.config_parameter` records, which are only accessible for the sysadmin and are used extensively by Odoo internal code.